# iPhone how to invoke a classes static function by string?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a static function defined in a class called "Character" as:

```
+ (UIImage) getImage;
```

I have a set of other classes that extend the “Character” class called “Bob” and “Jim”, each of these classes define a different file to get the image from. I need to be able to call get image based on the string e.g.

```
UIImage* image = [@“Jim” getImage];
```

However the above calls the getImage on the string class. I know it can be done like the following code snippet:

```
UIImage* image = [Jim getImage];
```

However I have a string not the object Jim. I suppose I could do a if statement that maps the string to a class but im wondering if there is a better way of dynamically calling a classes static function based on a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`NSClassFromString`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000055-BCIJDAJA):

```
UIImage* image = [NSClassFromString(@“Jim”) getImage];
```